# Can you connect to a Minecraft not on your WiFi network?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is it possible to connect to a Minecraft world that isn't on your WiFi network?  Say, if you live across the country from your friend you want to play with?

Comment: Are you asking in relation to opening your world to LAN?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to connect to someone not on your LAN (your personal network, including WiFi/wireless and direct connection).  The first and easiest is one of the players setting up a private Minecraft server, and then connecting to it like any other server.

The second, if for some reason hosting a server isn't an option, is to use VLAN, or virtual networking software, like Hamachi or Tunngle.  This tricks your computers into thinking they're on the same network, even when they're miles apart, and lets you connect to each other via LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you'll need the person who has the world you want to play on to run Minecraft's server software.

There are plenty of tutorials online of how to start up a Minecraft server on your computer, but as a brief guide:

They will first need to log in and download the server software from [here](https://minecraft.net/download). Then, move the downloaded exe/jar/dmg to a folder somewhere, and run it.

Once run, in the eula.txt it generates they need to change `eula=false` to `eula=true`. Next, they should locate the world that you both want to play on on their computer, move/copy it to the folder they ran the server in, and rename the world folder to "world".

Finally, they will need to [portforward](http://portforward.com/), the method by which they do so will vary by router. After that, they can run the server, and the other player can connect by using the server host's [external IP](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=opera&q=what+is+my+external+ip).

---

Alternatively, you can use a program such as Hamachi, which allows you to join the same game either over LAN or on a server without needing to portforward.